# MySQL refuses to work with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2 on Windows 7 or Win2k3

Tags: php, mysql, apache

MySQL refuses to work with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2.

I have been working with a friend who is trying to get this to work on Windows 7 64bit and I have been trying on Windows 2003 Server and we both have the same problem - MySQL will not be recognized. From the command line MySQL works fine, but PHP and/or Apache will not load the MySQL modules.

phpinfo() does not show it is installed. Apache and PHP work fine.

Anyone have any ideas? Be aware that I have already been on at least 100 sites and have read 100's of articles on how to fix this. So I am looking for concrete info on this, not speculation.

No insults to anyone intended, but after 3 days and long distance calls to California from Ontario, I need results before I go broke and go insane.

Comment: I kind of need more details than just 'it doesn't work'. Whats your php.ini config look like? Do you have extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll uncommented?

Comment: WAMP is hassle free - there's an addon that allows you to switch between mysql versions. I recommend toad for mysql too :)

Answer (score 1):

Look for `php\ext\php_mysqli.dll` on your filesystem (this is the path in the [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) install). It's only PHP that needs this module, Apache only needs to execute PHP. So check you have

```
extension=php_mysql_libmysql.dll
```

in `php\php.ini`. along with a config section for MySQL

```
[MySQLi]
mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
mysqli.allow_persistent = Off
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.default_port = 3306
...
```

What errors do you get trying to use the `mysqli_query()` etc functions?

If you really can't get it working, the excellend [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) will install a full *AMP stack on your OS of choice with very little hassle.

**edit:** @Beauford if the function's undefined then the library is not loaded. Follow above instructions for MySQLi, if in this still doesn't work package installation steps are [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php) along with a perhaps relevant Win7 [troubleshooting guide in the comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php#99763) (copied verbatim):

> to enable the mysql_... and mysqli_...
>   functionality, i opened the php.ini
>   file to uncomment the following lines:
>
> ```
> ;extension=php_mysql.dll
> ;extension=php_mysqli.dll
> ;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
> ```
>
> but phpinfo() still stated that no
>   mysql extensions were loaded. i tried
>   the fixes and suggestions above with
>   no success. so i invoked the windows
>   shell and typed ("Path" environment
>   variable set to the PHP & MySQL
>   directories): `php.exe -m`
>
> this returned the following error:
>   `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
>   library 'C:\php5\php_mysql.dll' -
>   Module not found.`
>
> this told me that PHP didn't recognize
>   what i thought was the extensions
>   directory. it searched all other
>   places first (sys-dir, workin'-dir,
>   the MySQL "bin" dir because of the
>   "Path" variable set, and even a
>   curious directory "C:\php5" that
>   doesn't even exist on my mashine) but
>   not the expected "ext" directory.
>
> so the fix was to go to "php.ini"
>   again and uncomment the following
>   line:
>
> `;extension_dir="ext"`

Comment: As mentioned, all this has been done, although mysqli is not used, I get a call to undefined function mysql_connect() error.

Comment: I have never heard of xampp, btu might be an option. Thanks